# Cannot find module 'crypto-js' Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: node.js, node-red

I am working with node-red and I am facing some issues with some packages I have downloaded from this [github](https://github.com/willem4ever/node-red-ttn). I have followed the instructions to get npm and to install it but I get error with missing libraries that are present in my system, have anyone experienced the same?

Thanks in advance!

```
lo@lo-desktop:~$ sudo npm install crypto-js
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/crypto-js
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/crypto-js
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/crypto-js/-/crypto-js-3.1.6.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/crypto-js/-/crypto-js-3.1.6.tgz
crypto-js@3.1.6 node_modules/crypto-js

locate crypto-js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/CONTRIBUTING.md
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/LICENSE
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/README.md
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/aes.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/bower.json
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/cipher-core.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/core.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/crypto-js.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/docs
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/enc-base64.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/enc-hex.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/enc-latin1.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/enc-utf16.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/enc-utf8.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/evpkdf.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/format-hex.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/format-openssl.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/hmac-md5.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/hmac-ripemd160.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/hmac-sha1.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/hmac-sha224.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/hmac-sha256.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/hmac-sha3.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/hmac-sha384.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/hmac-sha512.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/hmac.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/index.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/lib-typedarrays.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/md5.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/mode-cfb.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/mode-ctr-gladman.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/mode-ctr.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/mode-ecb.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/mode-ofb.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/package.json
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/pad-ansix923.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/pad-iso10126.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/pad-iso97971.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/pad-nopadding.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/pad-pkcs7.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/pad-zeropadding.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/pbkdf2.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/rabbit-legacy.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/rabbit.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/rc4.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/ripemd160.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/sha1.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/sha224.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/sha256.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/sha3.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/sha384.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/sha512.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/tripledes.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/x64-core.js
/home/lo/node_modules/crypto-js/docs/QuickStartGuide.wiki



lo@lo-desktop:~$ node-red -v
Welcome to Node-RED
===================

12 Apr 09:11:41 - [info] Node-RED version: v0.13.4
12 Apr 09:11:41 - [info] Node.js  version: v0.10.25
12 Apr 09:11:41 - [info] Linux 4.2.0-27-generic ia32 LE
12 Apr 09:11:41 - [info] Loading palette nodes
12 Apr 09:11:43 - [warn] ------------------------------------------
12 Apr 09:11:43 - [warn] [rpi-gpio] Info : Ignoring Raspberry Pi specific node
12 Apr 09:11:43 - [warn] [TTN] Error: Cannot find module 'crypto-js'
12 Apr 09:11:43 - [warn] ------------------------------------------
12 Apr 09:11:43 - [info] Settings file  : /home/lo/.node-red/settings.js
12 Apr 09:11:43 - [info] User directory : /home/lo/.node-red
12 Apr 09:11:43 - [info] Flows file : /home/lo/.node-red/flows_loshora-desktop.json
12 Apr 09:11:43 - [info] Server now running at http://127.0.0.1:1880/
12 Apr 09:11:43 - [info] Starting flows
12 Apr 09:11:43 - [info] Started flows
```

Comment: try installing specific version for your current node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like you ran npm install crypto-js in the wrong directory. Is you project located in /home/lo/ ?

You have 3 possibilities:

1. run "sudo npm install -g crypto-js" to have it available globally on
   your machine for all projects
2. run "sudo npm install crypto-js" in the root of your project
3. (best option) put your dependency into package.json (configuration
   file for NPM) and run "sudo npm install" in the root of the project

   - this will install all dependencies from the package.json

Comment: it seems it was that, I have used your option 1 and it did work. The option 3 indeed was the preferred, but while installing from github I got error from nmp of the sort `npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34` so I was doing it manually

Comment: You might want to update to the newest npm/node version, can be done like so on Ubuntu: 
`sudo npm cache clean -f`
`sudo npm install -g n`
`sudo n stable`

or maybe need to clear the cache of NPM (just run the first command).

Answer (score 2):

You should `npm install crypto-js` inside that `node-red-ttn` folder ; or globally.

Comment: I just ran  "npm install crypto-js"  inside project and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Was using typescript and nothing worked till I ran

```
$ npm i --save-dev @types/crypto-js
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me but inside the directory of your project write this:

```
npm install crypto-js
```